# What is the opposite of bored stiff?

Tags: synonyms, collocation

I'm reading "Cambridge Collocation in use" and find this sentence 
( I’m bored stiff in this lesson!) so can I use Stiff with another word to make the sentence opposite? 
Thanks

Comment: _Stiff_ collocates only with _bored_, not with any antonyms. In fact, given what the antonyms of _bored_ mean, it would probably be a very, very bad idea to use _stiff_ with them. If you say that you are ‘excited stiff’, for example, people would almost certainly interpret it as you saying that you have an erection.

Comment: I agree with @JanusBahsJacquet but in some very limited context  you might get away with “frozen stiff” meaning *transfixed*...

Comment: 'I'm thrilled to pieces ...'

Comment: Thrilled to **bits** was more usual in my upbringing; along with ***love** to pieces* (which I admit makes little sense on the surface).

Comment: (an additional option, not saying yours is wrong)

Comment: Flexibly excited.

Comment: “I’m (bored) stiff” appears to be an example of “I’m (anything) stiff” but if the operative phrase is really '(bored) stiff’ rather than just plain ’stiff’ then doesn’t the very Question make itself pointless?

There is tiny justification in the theoretical construction “I’m (excited) stiff” but that works best only as an example of how or why generic rules don’t always translate into specific cases.

Quite why semantically or grammatically “I’m stiff” is always sufficient unto him- (or “I’m wet… to her-) self is always sufficient unto itself would be a very different Question…

Comment: a decent ? for the ELL forum.

Answer (score 2):

The OP is asking for the antonym of *bored stiff* and asks

> … can I use *stiff* with another word to make the sentence opposite?

The short answer is ***no***.

The noun *stiff*, if I'm not mistaken, is slang for a dead body when *rigor mortis* sets in, the condition that occurs naturally in a corpse. When [rigor mortis](http://www.deathreference.com/Py-Se/Rigor-Mortis-and-Other-Postmortem-Changes.html) sets in, the body becomes cold, "rigid", and inflexible.

> Once the heart stops beating, blood collects in the most dependent parts of the body (livor mortis), **the body stiffens** (rigor mortis), and the body begins to cool (algor mortis).

To be *bored stiff*, therefore, means to **be bored to death**, and I doubt anyone has ever said they were ***interested in*** {something} ***to death***, unless it was said in jest or irony.

Edwin Ashworth and Will Crawford, in the comments, suggested

> thrilled to pieces (and) thrilled to bits

Oxford Dictionaries supplies the following definition of "to bits"

> **[to bits](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/to_bits)**
>   2. informal. Very much; to a great degree.
>
> - ‘Vicky was thrilled to bits’
> - ‘I just love him to bits’

Obviously, the opposite of *bored* is *interested* and in British English, we have the rather quaint, albeit old-fashioned, phrase

> ### [to be (as) keen as mustard](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as-keen-as-mustard)
>
> very eager and interested in everything  (Cambridge Dictionary)
>
> - ‘Admittedly I'm enjoying myself and like any other teenager [**I'm as keen as mustard**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/(as)_keen_as_mustard).’ (Oxford Dictionaries)

Comment: Just a (very belated) thought, but ***stunned*** is sort-of cognate to *stiff* :o) (and can mean *gobsmacked* in a very-pleasantly-surprised manner).

Comment: (although I now realise it's probably more common to use it to mean shocked in a negative way ...)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, you can't use ________ stiff to mean the opposite of bored, or excited, except as @Janus Bahs Jacquet commented *excited stiff’.... people would almost certainly interpret it as you saying that you have an erection*.

For a phrase that means the opposite of bored stiff, try

I'm all ***aquiver***.  From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/aquiver):

> in a state of trepidation or vibrant agitation; trembling; quivering
>   (usually used predicatively):   The bamboo thicket was aquiver with
>   small birds and insects. The exciting news set me aquiver.

The link has this illustrative sentence which uses aquiver as exactly the opposite of bored stiff:

> The entire audience was aquiver with suspense, keen to the point of
>   anguish.
>
> The Surprises of Life
>   Georges Clemenceau

And, used ironically in a reverse twist to mean bored stiff, from [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/aquiver):

> If that hasn't set your heart aquiver, the clincher is that the site
>   has been produced by the Department for Education and Skills.

(This means that anything produced by a government department will bore you stiff.)

Answer (score 0):

"Bored stiff" almost certainly originated as wordplay on "board stiff" or "stiff as a board".  The antonym would thus be something along the line of "spaghetti soft".

Answer (score -3):

“I’m (bored) stiff” appears to be an example of “I’m (anything) stiff” but if the operative phrase is really '(bored) stiff’ rather than just plain ’stiff’ then doesn’t the very Question make itself pointless?

There is tiny justification in the theoretical construction “I’m (excited) stiff” but that works best only as an example of how or why generic rules don’t always translate into specific cases.

Quite why semantically or grammatically 'I’m stiff' to him- (or 'I’m wet…' to her-) self is always sufficient unto itself would be a very different Question…

Comment: I'm not sure this actually addresses the question of producing the requested antonym.

Comment: Lawrence, in my view it did, clearly. Could your doubt stem from the non-existence of "the requested antonym"?

I hadn't noticed and Hot Licks' Answer might be wholly true, too.